# How to check or find if there is inbuilt method I can use in xcode documentation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am a recent xCode developer and I would like to know how to know or find methods like convert numberFromString available as in-built method in xCode which I can use rather trying to manually code with type cast and conversions. Any suggestions to find such methods or best way to utilize xCode documentation ?

Opening the documentation and manually searching for a method in that class or it's inherited classes is like searching a needle in the haystack. Can we search with keywords like 'convert number from string' and I will be notified of such equivalent methods in inherited classes ? Because say I was working with a string, get and set. But NSNumberFormatter class has numberFromString method. How will I be able to know of it's availability in such cases ? Hope this was clear to put my difficulty in finding methods.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

1. Press the option key on the keyboard and click on the class you want to know about. You'll get a nice popup with information.

Or 2. For a more in depth experience, press command and click on the class, you'll go to the class definition with the the documentation in the right panel under quick help.

Comment: Opening the documentation and manually searching for a method in that class or it's inherited classes is like searching a needle in the haystack. Can we search with keywords like 'convert number from string' and I will be notified of such equivalent methods in inherited classes ? 

Because say I was working with a string, get and set. But NSNumberFormatter class has numberFromString method. How will I be able to know of it's availability in such cases ? Hope this was clear to put my difficulty in finding methods.

Comment: I shall edit the question with the added above comment as well.

Comment: Any suggestions on my added query / comment ?

Comment: I think ask get more familiar with the Swift dev and iOS frameworks you will start understanding the patter of how most things are done.